# cannot install or use ZeroMQ library

Tags: zeromq

I am working on Debian Linux / Apache (a VPS at Dreamhost). I have tried to install ZeroMQ (version 3.2.3) as per [these instructions](http://www.zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software). At the first glance, it looks like everything went well.

The `sudo make install` command proudly reports back that (among others)

`Libraries have been installed in: /usr/local/lib`

Indeed, here is the `ls` of `/usr/local/lib`:

`libzmq.a   libzmq.so    libzmq.so.3.0.0  php        python2.5  site_ruby`
`libzmq.la  libzmq.so.3  ocaml            pkgconfig  python2.6`

In order to use ZeroMQ I have added to my php.ini:

`extension = /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so`

But when I run PHP, I get:

`PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) '/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so`

**What am I doing wrong?**

**update**
As per djf's answer, I worked my way through the [instructions for PHP bindings](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php) (building from Github). Those seem to work. But then, when I run PHP I get:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: 
zmq: Unable to initialize module Module compiled with module API=20060613 
PHP compiled with module API=20100525 
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0`
```

Now what?

**update 2**

Oh, wait a minute. I may know what that is. Dreamhost has PHP 5.2 on the command line. I need PHP 5.4, so I have been calling PHP like so `/usr/local/php54/bin/php` (this is apparently where the PHP 5.4 executable resides).

However, commands like `configure` and `make` use the ordinary, standard PHP. So I needed to upgrade CLI PHP to 5.4.

After that, everything worked. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: you need to build the bindings apparently ( considering what your requirements are ) not the library itself. http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php

Comment: @Ivo It's a shot in the dark, but maybe calling /usr/local/php54/bin/phpize will help? Otherwise _configure_ may provide a switch to force it to use a specific PHP version. I'm really not familiar enough with PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you've only installed the C library, hence the error:

`PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) '/usr/local/lib/libzmq.so`

You also have to build the PHP bindings. Check these [instructions](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aphp) on howto build them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I worked my way through the instructions for PHP bindings (building from Github). Those seem to work. But then, when I run PHP I get: 
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: zmq: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
Now what?

Answer (score 1):

I do this for windows but i thinks linux is same.
Just go to http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.2/windows and download package that fit with your php version. 
Then extract it and coppy 'libzmq.dll' to 'xampp/php' folder, 'php_zmq.dll' to 'xampp/php/etc'.
At the end of 'php.ini' add following line:extension=php_zmq.dll

Don't forget restart your xampp!Good luck